# Google Visualization Barchart - increase label padding / distance from label to chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using the Google Visualization API to generate some pretty simple bar charts. The only slight complication is that the labels can be very long. The client is fine with them truncating but wants to give the chart a little more space.

Try as I might, I cannot find a way to increase the distance from the labels to the chart area! The irritating things is that if the labels are all short, the padding is fine; as soon as they get long, they all right align right up to the chart before truncating.

I've tried various `chartArea.width` /  `chartArea.left` combinations, no joy; tried adding padding and margins to the `vAxis.textStyle` in the hope that the documentation is just incomplete; no joy.

I cannot believe that with all the other trillions of configuration options there is no way to increase label padding!

[image: Screenshot]

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9v6os5x6/2/

EDIT: What it looks like it is doing is either calculating a decent padding for labels that fit and then not compensating for the ellipsis, or leaving a space that is exactly one ellipsis wide when drawing non-truncated labels, because if you set all labels to be short then just increase one, what it looks like it is doing is filling the gap of the truncated one with the ellipsis, then aligning all the others.

This is much easier to see by fiddling with the fiddle than it is to explain in words :)

Comment: Not pretty, but is this what you want? : http://jsfiddle.net/9v6os5x6/3/